# how can i dispatch data rigth after get data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

if i act onPress={() => kakaoLosing()

i want to get data(which is profile) from getProfile by using async  await

and right after dispatch data to KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,

this is my code

```
            import {
            getProfile as getKakaoProfile,
            } from '@react-native-seoul/kakao-login';


            const Vieww = ({}) => {
            
            const kakaoLosing = useCallback(() => {
                
                const getProfile = async () => {
                const profile = await getKakaoProfile();
                };

                dispatch({
                type:KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,
                data:profile
                })
            },[]);

                return (

                    <Button1 onPress={() => kakaoLosing()} >
                    <Label>
                    profile
                    </Label>
                    </Button1>
```

but if i use this code

this error occure

```
        ReferenceError: Can't find variable: profile
```

how can i fix my code??

Comment: why are you using useCallback for that instead normal arrow function? is there any purpose?

Comment: You've closed over `profile` in the `getProfile` function scope, it isn't available in the `useCallback` hook callback. You then also don't call `getProfile` to make the request.

Comment: I don't see `async` keyword in your callback

Comment: please check out my answer, maybe it will help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've closed over `profile` in the `getProfile` function scope, it isn't available in the `useCallback` hook callback. You then also don't call `getProfile` to make the request.

I don't think there's a need for the `useCallback` hook. Just declare a normal `async` function and await the response. Now `profile` is in the same scope as the `dispatch`.

```
const Vieww = ({}) => {
  const kakaoLosing = async () => {
    const profile = await getKakaoProfile();

    dispatch({
      type: KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,
      data: profile
    });
  };

  return (
    <Button1 onPress={kakaoLosing} >
      <Label>
        profile
      </Label>
    </Button1>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way if you want it in separate functions:

```
    const Vieww = ({}) => {
        const profile = async () => {
          const data = await getKakaoProfile();
          return data;
        }

        const kakaoLosng = () => {
          const dataToDispatch = profile();
          
          dispatch({
            type: KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,
            data: dataToDispatch 
            })
        }
```

or even simpler:

```
        const Vieww = ({}) => {
            const kakaoLosng = async () => {
              const dataToDispatch =  await getKakaoProfile();
              
              dispatch({
                type: KAKAOLOG_IN_REQUEST,
                data: dataToDispatch 
                })
            }
```

and on button you can just pass:

```
return (
    <Button1 onPress={kakaoLosing}>
```